# Why orElse block of java always get executed?

Tags: java, function, lambda, option-type

I was playing with Java's Optional and thought that it works like an if else block. But in the following code even if the `name` variable is not `null` the content of the `orElse` block get's executed. Any explanation?

```java
import java.util.Optional;

class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "some text";
    System.out.println(
    Optional.ofNullable(name)
        .map(n -> mapped())
        .orElse(getOrElse()));

  }
  static String mapped(){
    System.out.println("mapped -- block executed");
    return "mapped";
  }
  static String getOrElse(){
    System.out.println("orElse -- block executed");
    return "orElse";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
mapped -- block executed
orElse -- block executed
mapped
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a closer look at [`Optional.orElse(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)). It takes a *value* which needs to be provided to that call but that value will only be *returned* in the else case. So `getOrElse()` will be executed to get that value in any case.

`Optional.orElse(T)` is normally used with already existing values, e.g. like this: `map(e -> mapped()).orElse("not found")`

If you want to use a function that will only be called in the else case you need to use [`Optional.orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) like this: `map(e -> mapped).orElseGet(Scratch::getOrElse)` (or `orElseGet(() -> getOrElse())`).

Answer (score 4):

the `orElse` part is not being executed. Your `getOrElse` method is being executed in order to pass a value into `orElse`, but when the `Optional` is evaluated the `orElse` branch isn't retruned.

If you want to lazily evaluate it, you could use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) and pass a method reference to it:

```
Optional.ofNullable(name)
    .map(n -> mapped())
    .orElseGet(Scratch::getOrElse));
```